# Loop "Addfriend" counting issue

Tags: php, regex, loops, while-loop

I am having this below code, It is work perfectly. But am having a small issue messuring the "$username_index" count.

the main idea of my code is following:

having accounts.txt [92 lines] usernames:pass format.
having usernames.txt [99999 lines] usernames format.

It will login to account1, then it will add 95 usernames, then next account2 , then add next 95 usernames.

But some accounts are giving response "Too many add friends". In this case response, I will skip the account and go to next.

But below code will contiue to the next 95!, so its skip 95 from usernames!

I want it contiue adding where the left username from skipped account.

I want it as soon it will login to the next account AND CONTIUING ADD THE NEXT LINE OF USERNAMES! no need to jump to next 95 username to add!

```
Example how i want it:

login account1
add username1
add username2
ERROR APPEARS!
login account2
add username3
add username4
add username5
add username6 
error appears!
login account3
add username7
add username8
etc..
```

Current Code:

```
$username_index = 0;
while(true) { // This is our while.. yes but this not for login()!
    try {
        $names = readFromFile("usernames.txt", 95, $username_index);
        if(count($names) <= 0)
            break;
        sleep(1);
        $fuckc = 0;
        foreach($names as $name){
            $ans  = $API->addFriend($name);
            $var_response = $ans->getMessage();
            if (strpos($var_response, 'too many friends!') !== false) {         
            printf("[!] Too many friends!, Skipping account now.\n");
            break;
            }
            if (strpos($var_response, 'Sorry') === false) {
                $fuckc++;
              printf("[+]" . "[" . date("h:i:s") . "]" . "[" . $fuckc . "] " . "response: " . $var_response . "\n");
              //printf("[" . $fuckc . "] " . "response: " . $var_response . "\n");
            }
            //sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
        }   
        $username_index += 95;
        $API->logout();
        //rotate_proxy();
        $API = null;
        //sleep(waiting);

        //$results = $findFriends->getResults();
        if (!isset($results) || count($results) == 0) {
            if(!login()) die("Could not find a valid account.\n");
        }
    } catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
            if(!login()) die("Could not find a valid account.\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited again : the counter `$username_index` only increasse when `$var_response` is not "too many friends!" :

```
$username_index = 0;
while(true) { // This is our while.. yes but this not for login()!
    try {
        $names = readFromFile("usernames.txt", 95, $username_index);
        if(count($names) <= 0)
            break;
        sleep(1);
        $fuckc = 0;
        foreach($names as $name){
            $ans  = $API->addFriend($name);
            $var_response = $ans->getMessage();
            if (strpos($var_response, 'too many friends!') !== false) {         
                printf("[!] Too many friends!, Skipping account now.\n");
                break;
            }
            else $username_index++; //◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
            if (strpos($var_response, 'Sorry') === false) {
                $fuckc++;
              printf("[+]" . "[" . date("h:i:s") . "]" . "[" . $fuckc . "] " .
                     "response: " . $var_response . "\n");
              //printf("[" . $fuckc . "] " . "response: " . $var_response . "\n");
            }
            //sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
        }   
//      $username_index += 95; //◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
        $API->logout();
        //rotate_proxy();
        $API = null;
        //sleep(waiting);

        //$results = $findFriends->getResults();
        if (!isset($results) || count($results) == 0) {
            if(!login()) die("Could not find a valid account.\n");
        }
    } catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
            if(!login()) die("Could not find a valid account.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest. the code moves to next account if error appears, or if it complete 95 adds. thats it.

Comment: @mzabox, what's the problem now? I'm here to fix it.

Comment: Now your code is working perfectly, but it stops for sudden, it doesn't loop infinite.